# Specify cassandra's port username, password, and host info while running cadence

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

While running cadence with cassandra externally, how can we provide the specific port, username, password of the cassandra.

With default port : 9042 and cassandra's authentication disable, we can run the cadence using below command   : docker run -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=10.x.x.x e ubercadence/server

How to specify different port, username, password?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply put ":9043" in the seed address as a different port.